# Easy Way To Convert A List To A String, Still Formatted As A List

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

This should be quite simple but I can't find a simple solution. Frankly this should be a one liner.

In Python 3, how can you convert a list, such as

```
['hello','world']
```

to a string that is formatted exactly the same, like

```
"['hello','world']"
```

I don't wish to split it into two words.

```
// This is bad.
"hello world"
```

I want to keep the traditional list formatting. I initially thought you could just bind the list as a string like (str)list_name but apparently not. Is there not a simple function for this?

EDIT:

I found thanks to AChampion that it was a simple syntactical error. I was trying to bind a list to a string like this:

```
//this is bad
(str)list_name
```

When I should have been writing it like this

```
//this is good
str(list_name)
```

That gives me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help and sorry I had to bring such a beginner question here. Still getting used to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both a lists `str()` and `repr()` forms are what you are asking for, assuming that the it is a list of simple strings.
If you have a more complicated structure and wish to transfer (serialize) to string form and back to object form you may want to look into the `json` module:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(['hello','world'])
'["hello", "world"]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply say:

```
lst = ['hello', 'world']
new_str = str(lst)
print(new_str) # prints out ["hello", "world"]
```

Python won't just convert the string to string format unless your explicitly tell it to. Like so:

```
lst = ['hello', 'world']
str1 = str(''.join(lst))
print(str1)# prints 'helloworld'
```

Or if you want a function:

```
def listToString(lst):
    new_lst = str(lst)
    return new_lst
```

Although the function is really more like a wrapper. I'd just convert the list using python bulitin `str()` straight up, rather then trying to put it in a wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: You can't do exactly what you're asking.

You cannot take any list that you typed in Python and get a string with the exact same original formatting. Python is pretty lenient with spacing within lists, so you can construct lists as such:

1. `['hello', 'world']`
2. `['hello','world']`
3. `[ 'hello', 'world' ]`
4. `[      'hello',         'world'       ]`

When Python creates these lists as lists, it doesn't preserve information about how you wrote it. So, there's not a way to get that back.

If you just want a stringified list, you should probably use [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).